# Make imageView of ListView Clickable to change image

Tags: android

I want to make change an Image when clicked on ImageView with other image I am having trouble doing so. This is my mainAcitvity code:

```
package example.sagar.com.imagtextview;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.msg_hover,
            R.drawable.projects_hover,
            R.drawable.number_one,
            R.drawable.number2,
            R.drawable.number3,
            R.drawable.number4,
            R.drawable.number5,
            R.drawable.number6,
            R.drawable.number7,
            R.drawable.number8
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
            "Indian Rupee",
            "Pakistani Rupee",
            "Sri Lankan Rupee",
            "Renminbi",
            "Bangladeshi Taka",
            "Nepalese Rupee",
            "Afghani",
            "North Korean Won",
            "South Korean Won",
            "Japanese Yen"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);




        // Item Click Listener for the listview
      /*  OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Country TextView
                TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tvCountry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };*/

        // Setting the item click listener for the listview
      //  listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        long id=getItemId(position);
        ImageView image= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear, do you want to change the image in an imageView when that imageView is clicked? All you have to do is define a click listener, assign that click listener to your imageView, and in the click listener you assign a new image to it:

```
imageView.setOnClicListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
        // or setImageDrawable, or setBitmap
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is where to add ImageView.setOnClickListener in program

Comment: Just create an anonymous class in your adapter, in getView().

Comment: i did that but creating two View gives me stackOverFlow Error

Comment: You forgot, you will also have to notify the adapter.

Comment: can any one give me certain example for this

Answer (score 0):

final ImageHolder finalHolder = holder; 
holder.imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ @Override public void onClick(View v) { finalHolder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlock); 
Toast.makeText(context, "grate work bro)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} });

### this worked for me but now i want to change only selected image

Comment: what i want to to is change particular image when click